# How to put multiple parameters in one $

Tags: php

Sorry if this is very obvios

I have the following

```
$a = 1200.00
$b = 675
$c = 123.00

$d = $a$b$c
```

How would I properly write $d

I thought it would be

```
$d = '$a'.'$b'.'$c'
```

How ever this is not correct

How can I make it so when asking to echo out `$d`
`<?php echo $d; ?>` it shows:
1200.00675123.00

Comment: what was your expected output?

Comment: I want the output to be 1200.00675123.00 but I dont know how to put it all into $d

Comment: what was your current output?

Comment: You can concatenate values... or sum up... or multiply, divide, subtract, combine, collect... or ... or ... or... There is no "right" or "wrong"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not JS, `.` will not sum up numbers, but convert it to string

`$d = $a . $b . $c;`

---

Please note, that you are working with float numbers, so sometimes instead of `1200.00` you can get `1199.999999999999999999998` and outputting it will trim your `.00` part.

That's why you need to use `number_format()` to output floats in format that you want:

```php
function getFloatStr(float $num) {
    return number_format($num, 2, '.', '');
}

$d = getFloatStr($a) . $b . getFloatStr($c);
```

[Example](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com?s=TY7BCoMwDIbPFvoOORS0INI55g5u7FGkVouF2UrXnra9-2J1YzmE_F_-_ORyW6aFEkqYhCscaiEqIVqUPcrmfFpHlTbHbUGJjlYF4yxo52cZCn13MryMDcBsnDk8KcmMhsI8OoRFghvN_Biit8mHUdl7jQOsnSPuR9_tuaurhLqEvMqx5RxP0gUb8KGvSXKofqL_F4qnd0c1OWBD-wE%2C&v=8.1.5)

Comment: still, this won't output what the OP is asking for!!

Comment: 1200.00 will be converted to 1200 and so on.

Comment: @OMiShah Yes, I was updating my answer with floats issues

Answer (score 0):

You are using ', hence the $a are not read as variable, but as a constant string:

```
$d = $a . $b . $c;
```

Will concatenate the three variables.

And since you declare $a, $b and $c as number, they are evaluated as such:

```
<?php
$a = 1200.00;
$b = 675;
$c = 123.00;

$d1 = $a . $b . $c;
$d2 = '$a' . '$b' . '$c';
$d3 = $a + $b + $c;

echo '<pre>';
echo "d1: ", $d1, "\n"; // d1: 1200675123
echo "d2: ", $d2, "\n"; // d2: $a$b$c
echo "d3: ", $d3, "\n"; // d3: 1998
echo '</pre>';
```

If you want to keep the 00, you will need either to use a formatting function, either to use quote:

```
printf("printf: %.2f%.0f%.2f\n", $a, $b, $d); // printf: 1200.006750.00
```

Or:

```
$a = '1200.00';
$b = '675';
$c = '123.00';
```

Comment: still, this won't output what the OP is asking for!!

Comment: 1200.00 will be converted to 1200 and so on.

Comment: Well, that's the magic of ~~precision~~  format for you :)

Comment: IK, still PHP should not do at least when concatenating!

Comment: I don't understand your comment; the number is stored as a number. And 1200.00000 is always equal to 1200 in math. Outputting 00 (or leading 00) is a formatting issue and converting a number to string _is_ one way to format a number.

Comment: ``+`` vs ``.``. If one uses ``+`` it's understandable about precision! The purpose of ``.`` is to join two values. Isn't?

Comment: No. What happens with . is simply a matter of converting the left / right operand to a string: the default format for numbers in almost every language (this apply to Java, C++, ...) is to represent the number without leading/trailing zero. PHP could also have taken a controversial stance and convert number using locale, for example you don't write `1200.000` in French, but  `1 200,000` (the decimal separator is not the point).

Comment: You're no wrong, sir :)